# Ubuntu forward X over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x-server

I've currently have the following situation.

I have a server, that is connected to the internet with ssh (on a non 22 port).
This is an ubuntu server without X server. 
Now i have a machine inside this network, that is used as a desktop machine.

Is it possible to forward all request on a specific port (for the server) directly to that desktop machine, to be able to use the Xserver over SSH?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the X client to appear on your desktop machine, the normal way I do this is with  `ssh -X` *servername*

Check to make sure your Display environment variabile is set via `echo $DISPLAY` and any xclient started from that X session will show up on your desktop x server.